# Cannot make an array by multiple Restangular responses

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am using Angular and have to populate a table and for this i need an array which has values by multiple calls to server.

I have following scenerio

**Angular Controller:**

```
  var application={};
  var data-[];
  $scope.tableData=[];
  Restangular.all("a").getList().then(function(arr1){
     for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
     {
     application.app=arr1[i];
        Restangular.one("b",arr1[i].id).get().then(function(obj1){
         application.obj1=obj1;
        });
        Restangular.one("c",arr1[i].id).get().then(function(obj2){
         application.obj2=obj2;
        });
     data.push(application);
     application={};
       if(i==arr1.length-1){
       $scope.tableData=data;
     }
    }  

  });
```

Now the table in view shows row equal to length of *arr1* and also shows the data in arr1 but the data by other Restangular calls are not attached with that array except last iteration.

OnlyiIn last iteration the array is fully made including arr1,obj1,obj2 other array indexes r missing obj1 n obj2.

This is because of async behaviour of Restangular response but cannot understand how to handle it.

**Note:**

**(Expected result)**

```
   data[
{
    app:{
        app_id:1,
        status:1
    },
    obj1:{
        name:"user1",
        gender:"male"
    },
    obj2:{
        telephone:"63532367",
        address:"abc"
    }
},
{
    app:{
        app_id:2,
        status:1
    },
    obj1:{
        name:"user2",
        gender:"female"
    },
    obj2:{
        telephone:"63532367",
        address:"xyz"
    }
},{
    app:{
        app_id:3,
        status:1
    },
    obj1:{
        name:"user3",
        gender:"female"
    },
    obj2:{
        telephone:"63532367",
        address:"xyz"
    }
}

 ]
```

**(Current Result)**

```
   data[
{
    app:{
        app_id:1,
        status:1
    }
},
{
    app:{
        app_id:2,
        status:1
    }
},
{
    app:{
        app_id:3,
        status:1
    },
    obj1:{
        name:"user3",
        gender:"female"
    },
    obj2:{

    }
}
]
```

Comment: You are overwriting the same property in each iteration of your loops. That's why you only see last one of each

Comment: data.push(application);
application={}; at this step i am pushing whole object to an array and empty it for the use in next iteration.

Comment: But before that you have a loop that assigns response of each request to exact same property each time

Comment: sorry that was mistyping.this part is inside the loop

Comment: Doesn't change the fact you still assign value to the exact same `application.obj1` numerous times in a loop. Only the last assignment will exist

Comment: in the same way i am assigning application.app=arr1[i]; in each iteration which is correct.actually in one iteration when application.obj1 is assigned in the same iteration this is pushed in an array and application is emptied.

Comment: Please show sample of expected results. You are not understanding what is what in each iteration. Also please properly indent code for readability

Answer (score 1):

`Restangular` is async (all the `Restangular.one()` is left before the callback you pass to `.then`). That's why Promises is used.

Even if it would be possible to make Restangular to be sync you shouldn't do that because this will block the browser until the data is requested which will be a bad user experience.

You should try to get into `Promise` as they were designed to look like sync code but behave async.

You can try something like this:

```
     var a = Restangular.all("a").getList().then(function(arr1){
          // Some modification of the backend data response
          return modifiedData; // Now this should be passed to each of those Restanngular.one() methods sequentially
     });
```

Above code will return the `Promise` that is returned by the `.then` call, which can be chained as following concept:

```
    (new Promise(function( resolve, reject){
       $timeout(function() {
         resolve("some");
       });
     }))
    .then(function(data) {
      return data+' data';
     })
    .then(function(data) {
       return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       $timeout(function() {
          resolve(data+' !!!!!!');
       });
     });
    })
    .then(function(data) {
       // this will have 'some data !!!!!!'
         console.log(data);
     });
```

Comment: Actually i metioned in my question that "This is because of async behaviour of Restangular response but cannot understand how to handle it." so kindly explain a bit that how this example can be handled according to your answer?